# Insert a function in bootstrap's javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a register form with bootstrap, everything is fine but i want to display an input when i click on a button. The html and css are working but i don't know where to put my javascript code. Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwNHJ/2/) .It seems like bootstrap's js can't be modified.

```
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Accueil</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/">

</head>

<body>
    <?php include("header.html"); ?>

    <div id="formulaireInscription">
        <h3 id="titreIncrivez">Inscrivez-vous!</h3>
        <div id="numstyle">


    </div>
        <form action="Inscription.php" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
              <div id="renseignementgenerale" class="form-group">
                <label for="userName">Nom:
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" placeholder="Entrez votre nom" required="required"></label><br />

                <label for="firstName">Prénom:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="Entrez votre prénom" required="required">

                <div class="form-group" id="birthdate">
                    <label>Date de naissance:</label>
                        <label for="dayInput">Jour</label>
                        <select name="day">
                          <option value="0">Jour</option>
                             <?php
                                for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++)
                                {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
                                }
                            ?>

                        </select>

                  <label for"monthInput">Mois</label>
                    <select name="month">
                        <option value="00">Mois</option>
                        <option value="01">Janvier</option>
                        <option value="02">Février</option>
                        <option value="03">Mars</option>
                        <option value="04">Avril</option>
                        <option value="05">Mai</option>
                        <option value="06">Juin</option>
                        <option value="07">juillet</option>
                        <option value="08">Aout</option>
                        <option value="09">Septembre</option>
                        <option value="10">Octobre</option>
                        <option value="11">Novembre</option>
                        <option value="12">Décembre</option>
                    </select>
                  <label for"yearInput">Année</label>
                  <select name="year">
                       <option value="0">Année</option>
                        <?php
                            for ($i = 2014; $i >= 1930; $i--)
                            {
                                echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
                            }
                        ?>  

                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="langueM">

                    <label>Langue maternelle:</label>

                    <select  name="langueM"> 
                        <option value="français">Français</option> 
                        <option value="anglais">Anglais</option> 
                        <option value="espagnol">Espagnol</option> 
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" id="langueE">

                    <label>Langue étudiée:</label>

                    <select  name="langueE"> 
                        <option value="français">Français</option> 
                        <option value="anglais">Anglais</option> 
                        <option value="espagnol">Espagnol</option> 
                    </select>
                    **<input id="i1" type="text">**
                   **<img id="plus" src="../res/images/boutons/plus.png">**

                    <label>Niveau:</label>
                    <select name=level id="niveau">
                        <option value="B1">B1</option>
                        <option value="B2">B2</option>
                        <option value="C1">C1</option>
                        <option value="C2">C2</option>
                    </select>
                    <a class="level" href=""><strong><em>Comment choisir mon niveau?</em></strong>
                        <span>
                            B1:Je participe à des conversations sur des sujets<br /> simples et familiers.<br /> 
                            B2:Je peux discuter avec aisance et une certaine<br /> spontanéité.<br />
                            C1:Je m’exprime spontanément sans trop chercher<br /> mes mots<br />
                            C2:Je m’exprime et comprends sans efforts et<br /> je souhaite maintenir mon niveau.
                        </span>

                    </a>
                </div>

              </div>

            <label >Adresse email:</label>

            <div>
                <div class="mailliste">
                    <input name="mailInput" type="text" placeholder="Entrez votre email" required="required"> @
                    <select name="schools" onchange="VerifListe();"> 
                       <option value="rms.fr">rms.fr</option> 
                       <option value="icade.es">icade.es</option> 
                       <option value="esb.de">esb.de</option> 
                    </select> 
                    <a href=""><img id="question" src="../res/images/boutons/question.png">
                        <span>
                            Vous pouvez vous inscrire<br /> uniquement avec <strong><em>votre adresse Email<br /> de votre école.</em></strong>
                            Pour consulter la liste<br /> des écoles patenaires cliquez ici.
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </div><br>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inscriptionInputPassword1">Mot de passe:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password1" placeholder="Entrez votre mode passe" required="required"><br>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" placeholder="Répétez votre mode passe" required="required">
          </div>
            <div class="myButtons">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Inscription"/> <input type="button" value="Retour"                                                            onclick="document.location.href='Index.php';" />
            </div>

        </form>    
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Put it in its own `<script>` tag?

Comment: Hum it works when i put the script in my HTML code but i wanted to know if it's possible to add custom functions to bootstrap js

Comment: what functions do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Kuma bootstrap.js is just a file containing js. Of course you can append any code you want anywhere, as log as it is correct js. What's your question/problem?

Comment: @moatz i want to replace my image by an input onclick

Comment: @wumm it's working when i put the code between <script></script> in my html. I just wanted to do it through the bootstrap.js

Comment: @Kuma that is bad practice. You should have an additional file to override. That way when you update bootstrap, you do not wipe out your changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a good idea to modify the bootstrap js code. I'd also recommend using the bootstrap CDN to help deliver faster load times for your users. As bootstrap is so widely used its likely to have been cached by the users browser and therefore won't put unnecessary load on your server to download to computers who already have it. You can add your own code by including it in a separate file and including it in a script tag. Something like:

```
<!-- js -->
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="yourCode.js"></script>
```

or use the bootstrap CDN instead:

```
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="yourCode.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several option to do this first of all you can use `<script>` tag and put all of your `javascript` code in that

```
<script>
 your code
</script>
```

I don't recommend that method because it cause confusion and messy code 
Another way is that to copy your `javascript` code in one `JS` file and then link it to your html file

```
<script type="javascript" src="your js path"></script>
```

This method is far more better that the last one.
**Note: It's better to put this script tag in the end of your html file because first browser should see your html then your Javascript.You can put it in the first of the page but it that case it's better to set onload event to your Js code to tell the browser run javascript when every thing is fully loaded**
And The last thing if you are using framework in your code put `js script` in the last of the page and use `CDN` for more efficiency of your page here is the link that you can find `CDN` links
[CDN JS](http://cdnjs.com/)